# How to escape curly braces @{u} of upstream in git alias (git-bash on windows)? [UPDATED]

Tags: bash, git, escaping

I have following alias in git config for pretty formatting

```
$ git config alias.lp '!git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an (%ar): %s"'
```

It is used in other aliases, here correctly working examples:

```
$ git config alias.la '!f(){ git lp -20 --author="${1-Baur}"; }; f'
$ git config alias.lm '!f(){ git lp --grep "${1-strange}"; }; f'
$ git config alias.lf '!git lp --follow'
```

But I can't find a way how to implement alias to see upstream commits.

This works:

```
$ git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an (%ar): %s" HEAD..@{u}
```

And this doesn't work:

```
$ git lp HEAD..@{u}
```

With error message:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD..@u': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

As you can see `HEAD..@{u}` became `HEAD..@u`, curly braces are lost.

After enabling `$ GIT_TRACE=1`:

```
$ git lp HEAD..@{u}
21:17:32.678084 git.c:560               trace: exec: 'git-lp' 'HEAD..@{u}'
21:17:32.679097 run-command.c:626       trace: run_command: 'git-lp' 'HEAD..@{u}'
21:17:32.683098 run-command.c:626       trace: run_command: 'git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an (%ar): %s"' 'HEAD..@{u}'
21:17:32.726084 git.c:328               trace: built-in: git 'log' '--pretty=format:%h - %an (%ar): %s' 'HEAD..@u'
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD..@u': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

How should I escape curly braces in `git lp HEAD..@{u}` in git bash on windows?

**[UPDATE]**
Thanks to **@phd** for pointing out there is no problem on linux!
I checked that this escaping problem is only on git bash on windows.
Native ubuntu and ubuntu on windows have no this problem.
But I have to use windows version. So I am still looking for solution.

```
$ git --version
git version 2.14.1.windows.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found correct escaping for git-bash on windows

```
$ git lp \'HEAD..@{u}\'
$ git config alias.lu '!git lp \'\'HEAD..@{u}\'\' #'
$ git lu
```

And for gitconfig

```
[alias]
  lu1 = "!git lp \\'HEAD..@{u}\\'"
```

Comment: After update to `git version 2.18.0.windows.1`
I discovered they fixed the issue, so we don't need escaping any more:

   `$ git lp HEAD..@{u}`
   `$ git config alias.lu '!git lp HEAD..@{u}'`
   `$ git lu`

And for gitconfig    
     ` lu = !git lp HEAD..@{u}`

Answer (score 2):

Works for me:

```
$ git --version 
git version 2.11.0

$ git config alias.lp '!git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an (%ar): %s"'

$ git config alias.lp
!git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an (%ar): %s"

$ git lp HEAD~..@{u}
fc4c763 - Oleg Broytman (5 weeks ago): Build, Tests(tox): Python 3.7

$ GIT_TRACE=1 git lp @~..@{u}
15:57:15.464236 git.c:600               trace: exec: 'git-lp' '@~..@{u}'
15:57:15.464326 run-command.c:350       trace: run_command: 'git-lp' '@~..@{u}'
15:57:15.465775 run-command.c:350       trace: run_command: 'git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an (%ar): %s"' '@~..@{u}'
15:57:15.466182 run-command.c:209       trace: exec: '/bin/sh' '-c' 'git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an (%ar): %s" "$@"' 'git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an (%ar): %s"' '@~..@{u}'
15:57:15.469076 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'log' '--pretty=format:%h - %an (%ar): %s' '@~..@{u}'
15:57:15.471285 run-command.c:350       trace: run_command: 'less'
15:57:15.471744 run-command.c:209       trace: exec: 'less'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have updated the question. It has turned out this problem only on git for windows.